# Window Click Event Javascript not work the first click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a question, this code works but the first click does not work, 
when I click the first time `window.open` does not work, only after second click it works.

```
let t = setInterval(function(){
        let x = document.createElement('p');
        x.className = 'text-style';
        x.innerHTML = games[cont];
        box.appendChild(x);
        if(cont >= games.length - 1){
            clearInterval(t);
        }
        cont++;
    },50);
    let gamesT = document.getElementsByClassName('text-style');
    window.addEventListener('click', function(){
        for(let i = 0; i < gamesT.length; i++){
            gamesT[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + gamesT[i].innerHTML, '_blank');
                });
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is `games` ?

Comment: doesnt the first click only adds event listeners to gamesT?

Comment: That's because you have to click the window to cause your other element events to be attached. Just remove the line for window.addEventListener and attach events to the gamesT array of elements right away.

Comment: games is a array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because when the element is created it doesnot have event listener attached. You can fix that by creating a function and pass that click. And also call it in each interval

```
let gamesT = document.getElementsByClassName('text-style');
let t = setInterval(function(){
        let x = document.createElement('p');
        x.className = 'text-style';
        x.innerHTML = games[cont];
        box.appendChild(x);
        if(cont >= games.length - 1){
            clearInterval(t);
        }
        cont++;
        addListeners();
    },50);

function addListeners(){
    for(let i = 0; i < gamesT.length; i++){
        gamesT[i].onclick = function(){
              window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + gamesT[i].innerHTML, '_blank');
         }
     }
}
window.addEventListener('click', addListeners);
```

Comment: did not work correctly now the first click works but when click try open alot windows I fixed calling function addListeners inside the if in setInterval, thanks for the answer, now works

Comment: @brunokoji Edited the code check it again. I used `onclick` directly instead of `addEventListener`

Comment: I fixed calling function addListeners inside the "if" in setInterval, thanks for the answer, now works

Comment: hey why addEventListener in gamesT open more than one window chanted to onclick event like you said fixed but why?